# Although not exceed index, I get error by the index

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

My question is 
( - Write the following method that merges two sorted lists
into a new sorted list. Write a test program that prompts the user to enter two sorted lists and displays the merged list. Here is a sample run. Note that the first number in the input indicates the number of the elements in the list. - )

When I run this code, Eclipse give error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at single_dimension_all_arrays.Merge_two_sorted_lists.getNumber(Merge_two_sorted_lists.java:60)
at single_dimension_all_arrays.Merge_two_sorted_lists.main(Merge_two_sorted_lists.java:77)
```

I can't understand why give the error. I can't exceed index.

---

```
    private static void sort(int [] list3)
        {
            int temp=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < list3.length; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < list3.length; j++) 
                {
                    if(list3[i]<list3[j])
                    {
                        temp=list3[i];
                        list3[i]=list3[j];
                        list3[j]=temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < list3.length; i++) 
            {
                System.out.println(list3[i]);
            }
        }

    private static void getNumber(int [] list1,int [] list2)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] list3 = new int[list1.length+list2.length];
        for (int i = 1; i < list1.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("Please, enter the number");
            list1[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < list2.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("Please,enter the number");
            list2[i]= scan.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= list3.length; i++) 
        {
            if(i<list1.length)
            {
                list3[i]=list1[i];
            }
            else if(i>list1.length)
            {
                list3[i] = list2[i];
            }
        }
        sort(list3);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please,enter the length of list1");
        int l1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please, enter the length of list2");
        int l2 = scan.nextInt();
        int [] list1 = new int[l1];
        int [] list2 = new int[l2];
        list1[0]=l1;
        list2[0]=l2;

        getNumber(list1,list2);
    }
}
```

Thanks..:)

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? Arrays in Java are Zero based

Comment: Of course. I enter the number for list3 while Program gets error.

Comment: Use a debugger to single-step through the code so you can understand it better. There are several fundamental logic errors above. For instance, in `getNumber`, you have `if (i<list1.length){...}else if(i>list1.length) { ... }` what if `i == list1.length`?

Answer (score 4):

> Although not exceed index...

Yes you do:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= list3.length; i++)
// ----------------^
```

The valid range of indexes is `0` to `length - 1`, so that should be `<` as it is in several other parts of your code.

---

Side note: You're also skipping the ***first*** element in arrays in a few places:

```
for (int i = 1; i < list1.length; i++)
// ----------^
```

Comment: @ArdaZaman: There may be something **else** wrong with your code, but this answers the question that was asked.

Comment: No. I find the solution. Solution is here.
 
else if(i>=list1.length)
   {
    list3[i] = list2[i-list1.length];
   }
. I can fixed it and the program give true reply :).
Thanks everything.